# Really run fetch multiple times synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I've seen various solutions for making fetch appear synchronous, such as using await, but then they must be wrapped in an async function, so the whole thing is then not synchronous.

I need to run fetch x times and to have each iteration complete in the order it was begun. If I use **.then** after fetch, that runs after each instance of fetch, but the results, including the results of the function run by .then, are returned in the order of response, so a list of urls fetched in order a-z, may be returned partly random order on output, which isn't acceptable.

I've tried using jquery ajax with async: false, and while that keeps the output in order with the input--when it runs successfully--it freezes indefinitely on error, and it's timeout value doesn't work in synchronous mode.

We seemingly have a choice of fetching multiple sequential urls in potentially random order, or we can get them *in order*, with jquery ajax / XMLHTTPRequest in synchronous mode, but then freeze the browser when a URL times out, while the timeout value we set to abort attempting to retrieve url is ignored.

Here's an example, which reads a text file of addresses, one per line, fetches their city council district, and appends it to that line. It works--except the output lines are not in the same order as the input, and I haven't found a way to get them to be, without freezing indefinitely on url timeout, in synchronous mode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><body>
  <h1>LAS - Find My District Widget</h1>
  <h2>Select a text file (.txt) with a list of addresses - each in a new line.  The Widget will return the corresponding districts.</h2>
  <input id="input-file" type="file">
  <hr><textarea id="output-box" cols="250"></textarea>
<script>
var baseUrl = "https://changedthistoprotectprivacy";
var input = document.getElementById('input-file');
var output = document.getElementById('output-box');

function writeSuccesOutput(geoclientResp) {
  var address = geoclientResp.input.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"");
  var cityCouncil = geoclientResp['results'][0].response.cityCouncilDistrict;
  var addressWithCcd = address + ' City Council District ' + cityCouncil + '\n';
  output.textContent += addressWithCcd;
}

function writeErrorOutput(error) {
  var address = geoclientResp.input.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"");
  var message = address + ' ERROR ' + error + '\n';
  output.textContent += message;
}

function geocode(address) {
  var querystring = encodeURI(address);
  var url = baseUrl + querystring;
  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(writeSuccesOutput);
  }).catch(writeErrorOutput);
}

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
  output.textContent = ''
  var addressList = event.target.result.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < addressList.length; i++) {
    geocode(addressList[i]);
  }
}

input.onchange = function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    reader.readAsBinaryString(this.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't have it asynchronous, your result order will be whichever comes first.

Comment: unlike xmlhttprequest, fetch can not be "made" synchronous - stop trying, embrace asynchrony - do you need the requests to be made in series, or can they be made in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Your actual requirement is to keep results in same order as the inputs so we can determine which coordinates belong to which address. You can use `Promise.all()` which resolves when given all promises resolves and return results in same order.

## Promise.all()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
  output.textContent = ''
  var addressList = event.target.result.split("\n");
  var prmises = addressList.map(address => geocode(address));
  Promise.all(promises).then(coordinates => {
    // here coordinates[0] is result for addressList[0] and so on
    
  });
}

// Here is a demo
const fakeApi = (address) => {
   const randrom = Math.random() * 1000 + 1000;
     return new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(() => resolve(`${address}_${randrom}`), 10);
   });
};

const addresses = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const promises = addresses.map(address => fakeApi(address));
console.log(addresses);
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: OK but then this waits for all the requests to complete and then adds them altogether into where they are supposed to go. `O(n^2)` time. OP is asking if there's a way to receive in order and insert as they come so when running concurrently he can do it in `O(n)` time. Or `O(2n)` if you want to put it that way

Comment: @ytpillai Read `Promise.all()` docs. It will not take `O(n^2)`. Time will depend on slowest api  call and all request will be executed asynchronously and `Promise.all()` will wait for all responces.

Comment: You're right sorry, I had a brainfreeze. Both work out the same

Comment: @ytpillai No problem. A was afraid, you are going to down vote. I happens many times :)

Comment: I generally try to comment and discuss it first before coming to that. Unfortunate that most SO users just straight up downvote without even an explanation.

Comment: Zohaib, thanks, but while this runs, eg if I convert the coordinates array to string and output that to the text box, the addresses are still in random order from one run to the next
as shown here: https://snag.gy/IlzJMk.jpg

when I run
...
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
  output.textContent = ''
  var addressList = event.target.result.split("\n");
  var prmises = addressList.map(address => geocode(address));
  Promise.all(promises).then(coordinates => {
    output.textContent = coordinates.toString()
  });
}
...

Comment: It appears that promise.all() still captures the outputs of the various fetches as they complete, or at least, when you output the coordinates array as a string, it's out of order with the input string. I tried to edit my comment, but was unable to save changes after 5 mins

Comment: @RalphSmorra I added an example and see how results have same order even if response was returned late.